# Starting usb on pro micro after deep sleep (ATmega32u4)

Tags: arduino-leonardo, arduino-micro

I have just started playing with a low power arduino project, and have managed to get the power drain down to about 220uA using `powerDown` from `LowPower`.

What I would love to be able to do is start the USB controller and send some data every 8 seconds, but I cant seem to send anything...

Any idea would be greatly appreciated :)

Her is my code:

```
// **** INCLUDES *****
#include <LowPower.h>

#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/power.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/io.h>

void setup()
{
  DDRD = B00100000;       // PORTD5 = TXLED
  DDRB = B00000001;        // PORTB0 = RXLed


  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) ; // Needed for Leonardo only
  Serial.println("Starter...");
  delay(100);
  Serial.end();

  /*
  *  IKKE FJERN DENNE!!! Da greier vi ikke å omprogramere kortet...
  */
  delay(10000);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) ; // Needed for Leonardo only
  Serial.println("low-power...");
  delay(100);
  Serial.end();
  flash();
}

void loop() 
{
  //LowPower.idle(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, TIMER4_OFF, TIMER3_OFF, TIMER1_OFF, TIMER0_OFF, SPI_OFF, USART1_OFF, TWI_OFF, USB_OFF);//, USB_OFF);
  LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_8S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);
  //USBCON &= B11011111; //Disable USB Freeze clock USBCON.FRZCLK
  //USBCON |= B10010001; //SET USB_MACRO_ENABLE_BIT USBCON.USBE

    PLLCSR |= B00000010;   //-Enable             PLL PLLCSR.PLLE = 1; 
    while (!(PLLCSR & 1)); //-Wait PLL LOCK      while (PLLCSR.PLOCK != 1);
    USBCON &= B11011111;   //-Unfreeze USB clock USBCON.FRZCLK = 0; (Clear to unfreeze)
    //-Clear Resume information ???

  flash();


  /*
  * Test USB kommunikasjon :)
  */
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  delay(5);
  Serial.println("Hello world!!!");
  delay(5);
  Serial.end();
   PORTD |= B00100000;
   PORTB |= B00000001;
}

void flash() {

   PORTD &= B11011111;
   PORTB &= B11111110;
   delay(100);
   PORTD |= B00100000;
   PORTB |= B00000001;
   delay(100);

   PORTD &= B11011111;
   PORTB &= B11111110;
   delay(100);
   PORTD |= B00100000;
   PORTB |= B00000001;
   delay(100);

   PORTD &= B11011111;
   PORTB &= B11111110;
   delay(100);
   PORTD |= B00100000;
   PORTB |= B00000001;
   delay(100);
}
```

Best regards, Richard

## EDIT

The manual specifies this resume protocol:
Resuming the USB interface (21.13 USB Software Operating Modes)

- Enable PLL
- Wait PLL lock
- Unfreeze USB clock
- Clear Resume Informtion

which I have translated into this:

```
PLLCSR |= B00000010;   //-Enable             PLL PLLCSR.PLLE = 1; 
while (!(PLLCSR & 1)); //-Wait PLL LOCK      while (PLLCSR.PLOCK != 1);
USBCON &= B11011111;   //-Unfreeze USB clock USBCON.FRZCLK = 0; (Clear to unfreeze)
//-Clear Resume information ???
```

It have no effect whatsoever, have no idea how to **clear resume information** though...

Also, for the record, the LEDs are flashing happily every 8 seconds.

Comment: You might have to put some delay after the serial.write. Once it comes back from sleep, it probably has to reestablish a USB connection (though your code seems to already account for that), and after that send the serial data. It can't do that when it's sleeping.

Comment: Hi Gerben, I just tried that with 800ms, but no success, I will try a little more... Is there any low-level USB commands that needs to be issued again maybe?

Comment: Also, when running in Idle, 200ms is enough before sending data and receiving... [edit] even 50ms is enough in when idle(usb_off) / serial.end before sending again

Comment: Sorry, I never worked with any USB chip, so I can't really help you any further.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to a similar question here:
https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=39214&start=15#p175098

Note: it requires you to close and open the serial monitor at proper timings.

```c
// disable the USB prior going to sleep
USBCON |= _BV(FRZCLK);  //freeze USB clock
PLLCSR &= ~_BV(PLLE);   // turn off USB PLL
USBCON &= ~_BV(USBE);   // disable USB

// and wake it up after
//routine to properly wake up
sleep_disable();
delay(100);
USBDevice.attach(); // keep this
delay(100);
Serial.begin(9600);
delay(100);
```